# Dropping and recreating index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have several tables that were created and were not assigned primary Keys.
The primary keys were also set to allow nulls. 
I would get an error when trying alter the potential primary key to not allow nulls:: Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 20.The index 'Missing_..' is dependent on column 'name'.

I learned that I would need to drop the index before altering the column, then add in the primary key and finally recreate the "missing" index.

However I need to know how to sript the index in order for me to recreate it.

Does anyone know how i can script it?

These are my current steps:

1. Drop Index
2. add primary key

Missing the Create index:

```
CREATE INDEX [Missing_..] ON table name ([what goes here?], [what goes here?]) INCLUDE ([what goes here?], [what goes here?], [what goes here?])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server drop and recreate indexes of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488734/sql-server-drop-and-recreate-indexes-of-a-table)

Comment: If you have nulls in the database- you need to populate them to something other than null PRIOR to setting Not Null.  Setting the primary key can be done in SSMS assuming you have permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to see what the index looks like is in SSMS Object Explorer go to

```
Databases > YourDatabase > Tables > YourTable > Indexes
```

Find the index you want to see, right click

```
Script Index As > Create To > New Query Editor Window
```

This will show you the code to create the index.

Comment: I followed your steps, which i was really excited and hopeful, and saw that my 'Script as' was grayed out.. Not sure why this would be

Comment: Are you using an elevated login to the database?

Comment: This worked!! I was able to get the index. I closed sql and opened it back up again.